# ORACLE detecting duplicate data even the text is lower or uppercase

Tags: oracle

I'm using `ORACLE` database. How to detect duplicate data even the text is lower or uppercase.

Assuming on my table already inserted : Production
Now I want to add: production (with lower case), it should be detect duplicate. In my current case, it was not detected and inserted.

Here is the sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_departments WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = '" . $getDepartmentName . "';
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: FYI: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UPPER (or LOWER) function, which capitalize your string, i.e.

```
 SELECT * FROM tb_departments WHERE UPPER(DEPARTMENT_NAME) = UPPER('" . $getDepartmentName . "');
```

As small variation you could capitalize your input string in the code and use

```
  SELECT * FROM tb_departments WHERE UPPER(DEPARTMENT_NAME) = '" . $yourUpperDepartmentName . "';
```

Moreover I suggest you use query parameters, instead of injecting directly the parameters string (`$getDepartmentName` ) in your query.